# Is there an integer z such that $255z\equiv 7\pmod {633}$?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I used the extended euclidean algorithm to

"Find integers x and y such that $633x + 255y = 6$, or explain why none exist."

And found that $6x = -58$ and $y = 144$. Now I'm stuck on the follow up question in the title. How do I proceed to answer a question like this?

Thanks

Comment: You probably noticed  using the extended Euclidean algorithm that the GCD of 255 and 633 was 3 - likely the follow-up question was checking that you understood the implications of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $255=3\times85$ and that $633=3\times211$. As such $255z\pmod{633}$ will always be a multiple of $3$. As $7$ is not a multiple of $3$ then there is no solution.